# A way to increase the height of an inline-block element beyond the font-height of its parent container with CSS only, IE9+ compliant

Tags: html, css

G'day.

I am working on a responsive website, and one of the blocks I need to include on every page contains image-links for various social networks. The images are inside an inline-block container which is in the same row as another inline-block element, so changing their height directly makes the container higher than its sibling, which is not particularly appealing. I am trying to find a way to increase their size from 16px (that's my font height) to at least 32px, because they are illegible otherwise. I have solved the problem by using `transform`, but I was wondering if there was a different way of doing it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Code snippet:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

a { display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
body, html { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #ffffff; }
img { border: 0; }
span { display: inline-block; }
textarea { resize: none; }

input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

.cblock { padding: 18px; border: 2px solid transparent; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5); box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5); -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }
.dtable { display: table; }
.dtcell { display: table-cell; }
.dtrow { display: table-row; }

#container { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#content { height: 100%; }
#footer { text-align: center; }
#footer span { width: 100%; }
#header > div { margin: 0 auto; }
#header > div .dtcell:last-child span:last-child a { padding: 0 10px; }
#header > div .dtcell:last-child span:last-child img { -ms-transform: scale(2, 2); -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2); transform: scale(2, 2); }
#logo { width: 100px; background-image: url('../images/logo.gif'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-clip: padding-box; }
#logo span { display: none; }
#menu span { width: 50%; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {

#header .dtcell { display: block; width: auto; }
#header > div { width: 100%; }
#logo { width: 100%; background: none; }
#logo span { display: inline-block; }
#logo span:first-child { padding: 18px; border: 2px solid transparent; background-image: url('../images/logo.gif'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-clip: padding-box; }
#logo span:last-child { float: right; cursor: pointer; }
#menu { clear: both; }
#menu div { display: none; }
#menu span:first-of-type { float: left; }

}

@media (max-width: 480px) {

#menu span { display: block; width: auto; }
#menu span:first-of-type { float: none; }

}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="dtable">
 <div id="header" class="dtrow">
  <div class="dtable">
   <div class="dtrow">
    <div class="dtcell" id="logo">
     <span>&nbsp;</span><!--
     --><span class="cblock">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dtcell" id="menu">
     <div class="cblock">
      <a href="#">Link #0</a>
      <a href="#">Link #1</a>
      <a href="#">Link #2</a>
      <a href="#">Link #3</a>
      <a href="#">Link #4</a>
      <a href="#">Link #5</a>
      <a href="#">Link #6</a>
      <a href="#">Link #7</a>
     </div>
     <span class="cblock">Phone</span><!--
     --><span class="cblock">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon0.gif" alt="" title=""></a><!--
      --><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon1.gif" alt="" title=""></a><!--
      --><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon2.gif" alt="" title=""></a><!--
      --><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon3.gif" alt="" title=""></a>
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content" class="dtrow">
  
 </div>
 <div id="footer" class="dtrow">
  <span class="cblock">&copy; The three musketeers, 2017. Say hello to the UFO.</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

(HTML comments are used to remove line breaks turning to spaces between inline and inline-block elements)

A copy of the code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uw35786p/2/

Comment: Could you not just change the padding of the right cell? https://jsfiddle.net/uw35786p/3/

Comment: @Pete, that would break the layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I64K.png I've tried that approach at the very start (changing container padding and increasing image height), but that would simply get the container "out of line" (the top border or the bottom border of the container would always end up on a different level compared to its sibling's).

Comment: There are no icons in your screenshot?  If you look at the fiddle, they seem to be lined up perfectly.  Anyway, I would have uesd flexbox if you want them to be equal heights - but this would involve a major restructure of your code as you seem to be using display:table (flex is the new approach that is better than table)

Comment: @Pete, [padding and changing image height does not solve the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/uw35786p/5/) - an example with icons. Flexbox is not IE9+ compliant, unfortunately.

Comment: That's because you removed the padding - https://jsfiddle.net/uw35786p/6/ and ie9? microsoft don't even support that anymaore!

Comment: @Pete, thank you. However, upon closer inspection, the bottom line of the right span seems to be about 1px higher than the bottom line of the left one. I have removed the padding because I thought you suggested to do so, to demonstrate I have tried out that approach before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways* to size a child and not affect its parent, using `transform`, which you already found, and absolute positioning, which could look like this

```
#header > div .dtcell:last-child span:last-child a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 14px;
  width: 50px;
}
#header > div .dtcell:last-child span:last-child img {
  top: -13px;
  left: 0;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw35786p/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
@charset "utf-8";

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

a { display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
body, html { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #ffffff; }
img { border: 0; }
span { display: inline-block; }
textarea { resize: none; }

input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

.cblock { padding: 18px; border: 2px solid transparent; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5); box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5); -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }
.dtable { display: table; }
.dtcell { display: table-cell; }
.dtrow { display: table-row; }

#container { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#content { height: 100%; }
#footer { text-align: center; }
#footer span { width: 100%; }
#header > div { margin: 0 auto; }

#header > div .dtcell:last-child span:last-child a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 14px;
  width: 50px;
}
#header > div .dtcell:last-child span:last-child img {
  top: -13px;
  left: 0;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo { width: 100px; background-image: url('../images/logo.gif'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-clip: padding-box; }
#logo span { display: none; }
#menu span { width: 50%; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {

#header .dtcell { display: block; width: auto; }
#header > div { width: 100%; }
#logo { width: 100%; background: none; }
#logo span { display: inline-block; }
#logo span:first-child { padding: 18px; border: 2px solid transparent; background-image: url('../images/logo.gif'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-clip: padding-box; }
#logo span:last-child { float: right; cursor: pointer; }
#menu { clear: both; }
#menu div { display: none; }
#menu span:first-of-type { float: left; }

}

@media (max-width: 480px) {

#menu span { display: block; width: auto; }
#menu span:first-of-type { float: none; }

}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="dtable">
 <div id="header" class="dtrow">
  <div class="dtable">
   <div class="dtrow">
    <div class="dtcell" id="logo">
     <span>&nbsp;</span><!--
     --><span class="cblock">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dtcell" id="menu">
     <div class="cblock">
      <a href="#">Link #0</a>
      <a href="#">Link #1</a>
      <a href="#">Link #2</a>
      <a href="#">Link #3</a>
      <a href="#">Link #4</a>
      <a href="#">Link #5</a>
      <a href="#">Link #6</a>
      <a href="#">Link #7</a>
     </div>
     <span class="cblock">Phone</span><!--
     --><span class="cblock">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon0.gif" alt="" title=""></a><!--
      --><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon1.gif" alt="" title=""></a><!--
      --><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon2.gif" alt="" title=""></a><!--
      --><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icon3.gif" alt="" title=""></a>
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content" class="dtrow">
  
 </div>
 <div id="footer" class="dtrow">
  <span class="cblock">&copy; The three musketeers, 2017. Say hello to the UFO.</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Well, one can of course set a fixed height on the parent and let the child overflow and/or be positioned relative.

Comment: Thank you, good sir. Well, that most likely means that `transform` and `position` are the only options. Another CSS mystery solved.

Comment: @Pyromonk Added an extra note in the end of my answer